# Input parameters of tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working through these tensorflow [codes](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/tree/master/models%20'codes') which implement a LSTM in tensorflow. While going through the codes, I came across this function (in [input_fn code](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/blob/master/udc_inputs.py) - line 38) `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features`. I looked up the documentation of `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/input_processing#read_batch_features). This is what I got -

```
file_pattern: List of files or pattern of file paths containing Example records. 
batch_size: An int or scalar Tensor specifying the batch size to use.
features: A dict mapping feature keys to FixedLenFeature or VarLenFeature values.
randomize_input: Whether the input should be randomized.
num_epochs: Integer specifying the number of times to read through the dataset. If None, cycles through the dataset forever. NOTE - If specified, creates a variable that must be initialized, so call tf.local_variables_initializer() as shown in the tests.
queue_capacity: Capacity for input queue.
reader_num_threads: The number of threads to read examples.
name: Name of resulting op.
```

There are few input parameters that I am not able to understand and was hoping someone could help me with it.

1. The `randomize_input` parameter. Does it mean it will shuffle the entire dataset?
2. For `num_epochs`, if I specify `None` does it mean that my `input_fn` will keep feeding to the `model_fn`. In that case the training wouldn't stop. This doesn't make sense to me. I guess I'm going wrong somewhere here.
3. `queue_capacity` I am not sure what this means

Would appreciate any help around these questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomize_input` means both that the filenames are randomized and that a shuffling queue is used to shuffle examples once in memory.

For `num_epochs`, training can stop due to other reasons (often training stops at a given `global_step` regardless of the input function).

For `queue_capacity`, TensorFlow uses queues internally to buffer I/O for maximum throughput. This parameter allows you to control the size of that queue.